# Looking for a post-apocalyptic trilogy where pilot is nursed back to health by natives of the land

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read a series of books around 2005. I think it might have been a trilogy.

Basic story line is in a post apocalyptic world. The main character is a pilot for the Federation or something similar to that. He crash lands, is nursed back to health by the natives, comes to like and respect them, and does not want to fight against them.

Also in the later book I think it also involves another race who are very Japanese-ish. They drink sake and the "clan" names are things like Fu-Jitsu and Mitsu-Bishi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-apocalyptic sci fi book series. Humanity lives below ground, 'ferals' above](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152531/post-apocalyptic-sci-fi-book-series-humanity-lives-below-ground-ferals-above)

Comment: @Mooz The question you linked was recently marked as a duplicate of THIS ONE. This question is from 2 years ago, and one you provided was asked 11 hours ago.

Comment: See this meta for clarification of why I've chosen to go the other way on this one: [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4744/21267). The "newer" question is of better quality.

Comment: @Mooz My apologies, then. But the newer one is marked already.
What happens if they marked the older one as duplicate of this one?
Would the duplicate on the newer question stand? I mean, I would find it weird if they were duplicates of each other.

Comment: @soulblazer No need to apologise, it's not a "normal" rule. Those who have marked the other one a dupe shouldn't have done so, they should have gone the other way, but that's ok; it will either get naturally corrected or ignored; either way, one is dupe of the other and people can see that, so all good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like Patrick Tilley's [Amtrak Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amtrak_Wars)

It's a series of six books, set after a war devastated present-day North America (and presumably the rest of the world.)

The Amtrak Federation (renamed to the Lone Star Confederation in later editions) live in huge underground shelters, and use technology to conquer the outside world; the surface is controlled by vaguely Native American tribes (the "mutes") who the Federation are conquering as they expand.

The main characters spend quite a lot of time captured by the other side. Steve Brickman is captured by the mutes when his plane crashes, and is nursed back to health by them, coming to realise that they're not the sub-humans he's been taught. At one point, he's taken to visit the Iron Masters, who are a Japanese-descended group of survivors, who have names that are taken from current Japanese companies.

There's also [a wiki](http://amtrakwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Amtrak_Wars_Wiki) if you want to risk spoilers....

Comment: You are a legend, thank you so much!