# Post apocalyptic world, American pilot travels time with 2 other pilots and wants to find them

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, post-apocalyptic

I don't remember names, but there is an American pilot flying along with two other jets when the bombs drop. They are somehow transferred into the future, many years after the bombs.

He then sets off on a journey to find the other two pilots in a world that is vastly changed and he knows nothing about it. He meets a woman from some kind of tribe who has mind reading abilities of some sort and she manages to understand him (nobody speaks English anymore, that far away in the future).

She learns English and decides to join him in his journey. She also becomes his love interest and vice-versa. There were many books as far as I remember - about a lake monster, coliseum with fighters who take drugs that make them strong but utterly stupid (one of the pilots was there).

If anyone knows the series please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Possibly [***The Amtrak Wars***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amtrak_Wars) - Related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99743/looking-for-a-post-apocalyptic-trilogy-where-pilot-is-nursed-back-to-health-by-n?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D - Sadly, no - no time travel in Amtrak Wars.

Comment: This has a _Planet of the Apes_ feel.

Comment: Whatever this is I am sad it does not have an answer