# Post-apocalyptic sci fi book series. Humanity lives below ground, 'ferals' above

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been trying to find an old sci fi book series I read when I was in high school (late 90's)

Humanity has ended up living underground in huge biodome types thing because the surface is ruined. Fast forward a long while and some people are going out to discover stuff & run tests etc.

There's a human species on the surface that are classed as "feral" and have suffered mutations. Cue the male adventurer coming into contact and eventually falling in love with one of the 'ferals'. Yadda yadda, they end up actually being quite complicated species with different tribes and almost *shogunate*-like ways.

Humans (from below the surface) end up coming after the guy.

Comment: You'd probably enjoy; http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20600454-falling-sky

Comment: Very similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Without_End_(film)

Comment: @Valorum I propose we got the other way with the dupe on this one. This particular question is of better quality than the one it has been closed as dupe of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly [***The Amtrak Wars***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amtrak_Wars) by Patrick Tilley.

> ..the **old world was destroyed in a nuclear war**, known in the books variously as 'The Holocaust' and 'The War of a Thousand Suns'. The United States and Russia were involved in this nuclear war but who fired the first shot is not known. The resulting war lasted only a few hours, but between the nuclear exchange and the years of nuclear winter that followed, the overwhelming majority of the human race was annihilated.

---

> The most organised band of survivors were the Amtrak Federation. Four hundred American citizens survived the nuclear war in a **vast underground bunker beneath Houston, Texas**. They established additional underground bunker-cities (known as divisional bases) linked by a high-speed subterranean rail network.

---

> Ordinary citizens of the United States who managed to survive the nuclear war and adapt to the radiation mutated into a **clan-based warrior society known as the Mutes.** Adopting a warrior ethos and tribal society similar to Native Americans, the Mutes are primitive, employing spears and knives in combat. They are affected by a variety of radiation-induced infirmities, such as somewhat short-term memories and deformities varying in severity by individual.

---

> ..newly qualified Amtrak pilot named Steve Brickman is taken prisoner by the Mutes but not killed, due to a prophetic vision of the clan's seer... [snip]... Steve comes to admire and respect the Mutes; **he falls in love with a "straight" (mutation-free) Mute woman named Clearwater**.

Comment: Hmm, I think I remember that one, and found the ending entirely unsatisfying.

Comment: @Sobrique That's probably because Tilley never really finished the series. It's covered in the Wiki article linked.

Comment: he's said he wants to finish the series (3 more books) so fingers crossed!

Answer (score 4):

It could be the Russian novel [*We*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_(novel)) by Evgeny Zamyatin.

Humanity lives in glass buildings in a city-state surrounded by a large wall:

> Like all other citizens of One State, [the protagonist] D-503 lives in a glass apartment building

---

People in the One State are interested in exploring:

> One thousand years after the One State's conquest of the entire world, the spaceship Integral is being built in order to invade and conquer extraterrestrial planets.

---

Protagonist develops feelings for a woman who doesn't follow societal norms:

> While on an assigned walk with O-90, D-503 meets a woman named I-330. I-330 smokes cigarettes, drinks alcohol, and shamelessly flirts with D-503 instead of applying for an impersonal sex visit; all of these are highly illegal according to the laws of One State.
>
> Both repelled and fascinated, D-503 struggles to overcome his attraction to I-330.

---

The 'feral' people living beyond the wall are not considered human:

> She [I-330, the love interest] takes him through secret tunnels inside the Ancient House to the world outside the Green Wall, which surrounds the city-state. There, D-503 meets the inhabitants of the outside world: humans whose bodies are covered with animal fur.

---

Humans from the One State come after the protagonist:

> In his last journal entry, D-503 indifferently relates that he has been forcibly tied to a table and subjected to the "Great Operation", which has recently been mandated for all citizens of One State in order to prevent possible riots